# Reading PHP encoded array with Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I created an array with PHP. I need help how to read it, with Android app.

Encoded array looks like this:

```
["id","string 1","string 2","string 3","string 3","string 4"]
```

I have to be able to read all of it's elements, with Android application.

It's created with PHP with code like next:

```
    $res = array();
    $res[] = $data['id'];
    $res[] = $data['string 1'];
    $res[] = $data['string 2'];
    $res[] = $data['string 3'];
    $res[] = $data['string 4'];
    return json_encode($res);
```

Can you please help me how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the `response` string that you get from the **PHP** server. (`json_encode($res)`)

Comment: This is response: ["id","string 1","string 2","string 3","string 3","string 4"]

Comment: Are you sure ? Have you tried to log it to the console ? Because `json_encode` should return something like `{ .. }`

Comment: It's what is returned when I put echo json_encode($res); instead of return json_encode($res);

Comment: You should use `echo` as far as I recall... plus, you should log it on the **Android client side**, not on the backend.

Comment: I get the same with echo or return

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97761/discussion-between-sparta-and-user198003).

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can use the following code to parse the response in Android. I have hardcoded the response that you are getting in the code, so you get the idea. Also I have written it in onCreate of my activity, you may write this wherever is suitable for your app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String strJson="[\"id\",\"string 1\",\"string 2\",\"string 3\",\"string 3\",\"string 4\"]"; // This is your response, with escaped " and used as a String

    try {

        //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains Strings
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            String data = (String)jsonArray.get(i);
            Log.d("MyData",data);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace(); // Not a good idea. But left it for now}
}
```

If you monitor the logcat with filter MyData you will find the output as:

```
D/DATAIS: id
D/DATAIS: string 1
D/DATAIS: string 2
D/DATAIS: string 3
D/DATAIS: string 3
D/DATAIS: string 4
```

There are a lot of tutorials in web that deals with how to parse JSON in Android. You can study them to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, when I added names to elements of PHP array:

```
$res = array();
$res[0] = $data['id'];
$res[1] = $data['string 1'];
$res[2] = $data['string 2'];
$res[3] = $data['string 3'];
$res[4] = $data['string 4'];
```

And on Android side:

```
JSONObject  mainObject = new JSONObject(ret);
String str1 = mainObject.optString("1").toString();
String str2 = mainObject.optString("2").toString();
String str3 = mainObject.optString("3").toString();
String str4 = mainObject.optString("4").toString();
```

Thank you all on help.